# PDO does not run when I upload to web hosting?

Tags: php, pdo

mysql is deprecated and people recommend PDO over mysqli. I followed tutorials to connect a submission form with a database and it worked on my localhost (I use xampp), but when I upload them to some free web hosting services, the PHP works, except when it uses PDO (e.g. when connecting to database).

I have tried quite many free hosting services but PDO doesn't work everywhere. I wonder if this is normal, is there any free hosting service that supports PDO, or do I have to do something for the PDO to work ? But I didn't do anything to my localhost server and it worked.

Comment: you pay NOTHING, so why should you expect to get much in return?

Comment: PDO requires a minimum php version of 5.1, have you checked if your hosts support it? check by using the phpinfo() function inside php

Comment: PDO is an extension and is not necessarily enabled. It also has different drivers for each DBMS that may or may not be installed/enabled. Check with your hosting company. Also, I think you'll find that actually paying money for hosting will get you a MUCH better experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like PDO Is not available, you can do something like this to check if PDO is installed/exists.

```
if(class_exists('PDO')){
 echo "PDO exists";
}else{
echo "PDO does not exist"; 
}
```

or

`var_dump(get_declared_classes())`  -- and see if PDO is there.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I am new, so I am not even sure whether it's possible that they don't support PDO, or whether I need setup something before I use it.

Comment: Don't worry, in time you will learn. We've all be there once. For now just check if PDO exists, if not upgrade your PHP version to `> 5.1`